# How to make a CLI in CustomTKinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, command-line-interface, customtkinter

How can I make a CMD like Command line Interface in python with CustomTKinter? Where the user can type a single line, press enter and the program will do its thing.

I've looked into the CTkTextbox, but cant seem to figure out how to make it into a CLI

Comment: I think this question is too broad for stackoverflow. There are likely many ways to do what you want, though they all boil down to providing a prompt, accepting input, and then acting on that input. Tkinter (and all other GUI toolkits) give you all the tools you need to accomplish that. It's not clear what specific part of the problem you're struggling with.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If what you say *"command line interface"* is used in a console/terminal without desktop graphical environment, you should not use a GUI library.  Use simple `input()` function for console input.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use simpledialog for this

```
from tkinter import simpledialog
answer = None
while answer != "quit":
    answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "What is your first name?")
    if answer is not None:
        print("Your first name is ", answer)
    else:
        print("You don't have a first name?")
```